# MySQL Error: Get Total Record using SubQuery Along with Pagination Query

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I'm trying to create my custom pagination using MySQL.

So far this is my query with sub query:

`select *, (select count(*) from customers) as totalCustomer FROM customers ORDER BY id LIMIT 20 OFFSET 10;`

But MySQL Workbench says, `Error Code: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: That syntax looks fine to me.  Which version of MySQL are you using?  Are you sending that exact query in the MySQL command line or through another programming language library?

Comment: it says, MySQL Server version is 8.0.21

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a dbfiddle?  That might help me figure out what the issue is.